# I am trying to append square of a list to the list

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
list1=[-4,-1,0,3,10]
for k in list1:
    list1.append(k**2)
```

I am trying to find the square of the numbers in list1 and then I am trying to add the square to the same  list1. But it is going to infinity loop. Can some1 help me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> list1 = [-4, -1, 0, 3, 10]
>>> list1.extend([x**2 for x in list1])
>>> list1
[-4, -1, 0, 3, 10, 16, 1, 0, 9, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

may be something like this

```
list1=[-4,-1,0,3,10]
list2 = []
for k in list1:
    list2.append(k**2)
list1 = list1 + list2
print(list1)
```

Or This

```
list1=[-4,-1,0,3,10]
list1 = list1 + [k**2 for k in list1]
print(list1)
```

http://ideone.com/vgZlXl

Comment: instead of for loop use list comprehensions.
list2 = [x**2 for x in list1]